# Only IE Browser gives org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

Tags: jquery, spring, internet-explorer, file-upload, multipart

I am trying to upload a file using jquery fileupload.js, spring. 
Code to **upload files works fine for Mozilla and chrome browser. But getting following error **only for IE browser****

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request.
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:74)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, which jquery fileupload.js did you use, post the link to the project.
If you referred the [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/), however, I met the same problem, the cause is I mismatched the **jquery.iframe-transport.js**, I used [another one](http://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/), and [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) use its own version, so, I downloaded [this version](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js) and replace the former, and no more this problem in IE.